# In C#, how can I sort a collection of objects by a seperate int array?

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

I have a collection of  **Person** objects and a Person object has an id property.

```
 var peopleList = new List<Person>();
 peopleList .Add(new Person(){Name = Joe, Id = 30};
 peopleList .Add(new Person(){Name = Tom, Id = 22};
 peopleList .Add(new Person(){Name = Jack, Id = 62};
```

I now have an array of integers that represents the ordering that i want to display the array

```
 var list = new List<int>();
 list.Add(22);
 list.Add(62);
 list.Add(30);
```

what is the correct way of sorting the **PeopleList** collection by the **List** array? so I get an ordering of:

```
Tom, Jack, Joe
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a lookup of ids to person objects:

```
var peopleLookup = peopleList.ToDictionary(person => person.Id);
```

Then you can go through your list of IDs, mapping each to a person:

```
var query = list.Select(id => peopleLookup[id]);
```

Comment: +1. Note that if you have duplicate `Id` (unlikely based on name of the filed) you'll need to convert to dictionary by hand instead of `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It seems pretty clear in this case that the Ids should be unique, and barring any other explicit requirements, I'd *expect* it to throw an exception.  If the ids aren't unique then I'd imagine the solution would be to first remove the duplicates, then use this exact code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.IndexOf(Id)`. Use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) to create a new list

```
var sorted = peopleList.OrderBy(x => list.IndexOf(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Or use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to reorder the list itself

```
peopleList.Sort((x, y) => list.IndexOf(x.Id).CompareTo(list.IndexOf(y.Id)));
```

Comment: Your second solution is O(n^2 * log(n)), for a problem that can be trivially solved in O(n) time.

Comment: Yeah, making a dictionary first could improve that, but your answer is better, so I didn't bother improving mine.

Answer (score -2):

Might be slow if collection is huge, but this works.

```
var peopleList = new List<Person>();
peopleList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Joe", Id = 30 });
peopleList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Tom", Id = 22 });
peopleList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jack", Id = 62 });

var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(22);
list.Add(62);
list.Add(30);

peopleList.Sort((x, y) => list.IndexOf(x.Id).CompareTo(list.IndexOf(y.Id)));
```